# how to add values in spinner in android

Tags: java, android, spinner, default-value

**hi .. this is my code i want to add values in my spinner .. but i don't know how i do this ..
ex A+=5
waiting for your help**

`import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     private Spinner spinner1, spinner2;
      private Button f;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addItemsOnSpinner2();
        addListenerOnButton();
        addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();

    }
    EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.o1);
    Button m = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b22);

public void addItemsOnSpinner2() {

    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("A+");
    list.add("A");
    list.add("B");
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list1.add("A+");
    list1.add("A");
    list1.add("B");
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
    dataAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter1);
}




public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new  CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
Button f=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);


f.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
            int gr1=Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString());

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
        "OnClickListener : " + 
              "\nSpinner 1 : "+ String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()) + 
              "\nSpinner 2 : "+ String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem()),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


      }

    });
}
}`

printf("%d\n", 42);  /* what was the
     question again? */
i don't know where exactly should i add the code who add values in spinner

Answer (score 3):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private SharedPreferences prefs;
private String prefName = "spinner_value";
int id=0;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

final List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("Item 1");
list.add("Item 2");
list.add("Item 3");
list.add("Item 4");
list.add("Item 5");

final Spinner sp=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
ArrayAdapter<String> adp= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
adp.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
sp.setAdapter(adp);

prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);
id=prefs.getInt("last_val",0);
sp.setSelection(id);

sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int pos, long arg3) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
//---save the values in the EditText view to preferences---
editor.putInt("last_val", pos);

//---saves the values---
editor.commit();

Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), sp.getSelectedItem().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
});

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that :

```
testSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.testSpinner);
ArrayList<String> list = <value come from somewhere>
testSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.testSpinner);
MyAdapter testAdapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinner_style, list);
testSpinner.setAdapter(testAdapter);
testSpinner.setSelection(testAdapter.getCount());
```